# How to pass value back to original caller c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that adds information to a list and then does some calculations. Now I want to return that to the original program. How do I do that?

In Main program I have public value

```
public string ResponseTime
{
    get { return _ResponseTime; }
    set { _ResponseTime = value; }
}
```

MAIN FUNCTION()

Within the main function I call the class which calculates the correct response time and returns it back. The question is how do I capture it in this main program?

`ListTest.CalculateResponseTime(_ResponseTime);`  - need to use the value that returns and set ResponseTime to that value.

```
public static string CalculateResponseTime(string responseTime)
{

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "original program", "main function", "main program" etc. Do you actually have more than one process?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `string` data type? Seems like a `TimeSpan` is more appropriate here...

Answer (score 2):

Are you just asking how to get the return value from a function??

```
ResponseTime = ListTest.CalculateResponseTime(_ResponseTime);
```

Comment: Yes basically..... becuase i need to use it in the main program which is the one that calls this class and then set the value of _responsetime in this case to the returned value form the function.....

Comment: public static string CalculateResponseTime(string responseTime)
        {
          
            var response = (int)Convert.ToDouble(responseTime);
            var LastValue = _list.Count - 1;
            var LogsummaryLatest = _list[LastValue];

Comment: if (PreviousArrayNumber > 0)
                {
                   
                    //var logSummaryPrevious = _list[LastValue - 1];

                    newResponseTime = (CurrentResponseTime - PreviousResponseTime);
                    
                }
            }
           
         
           return responseTime = newResponseTime.ToString();

Comment: when the value for response time is generated inside the method, you may actually only need `this.ResponseTime = ListTest.CalculateResponseTime();`

Comment: connot implicitly convert type void to type string error  ListTest.Record(_ResponseTime);
               //  ListTest.CalculateResponseTime(_ResponseTime);
                 this._ResponseTime = ListTest.CalculateResponseTime(_ResponseTime);

Answer (score 1):

pass the parameter by reference

```
public void  CalculateResponseTime(ref string responseTime)
    {
      // your code
    }
```

you don't need to return the string, becuase when your modify the value of your string in the function ,the value will be modified the the original location (memory address) and not only in the scope of your function.

In this way you can assign directly the property of your class as function parameter, and when the function ends your property has the value modified too.

The alternative is passing your parameter as value and return the reult as assign of your property.

if you need more information about it. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_referencetypes) is your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
ResponseTime = [insert calculated value]
```

(...at least, that's how I'm interpreting your question...)